# Set DataTemplate for a specific item in an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone, datatemplate

I have an `ItemsControl` that contains a collection of items that are shown at a page. 
The `ItemsControl` has an `ItemTemplate` property which is set to certain DataTemplate resource.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SimpleTemplate">
        <!-- .... -->
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ComplexTemplate">
        <!-- .... -->
</DataTemplate>
...............................
<ItemsControl 
      x:Name="MainCanvas"
      DataContext="{StaticResource mainItems}"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Buttons}"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SimpleTemplate}"
>

      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 <Canvas Width="4000" Height="4000" />
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>                       
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

</ItemsControl>
```

Is it possible to change DataTemplate for a one specific item in my ItemsControl programmatically?

Comment: How about a DataTemplateSelector? http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector

Comment: Based on what criteria do you want to set the data template?

Comment: Daniel, I want to set the data template after checking if an item in items source has  a boolean property which is set to 'true'

Answer (score 2):

Sound like you are looking for [ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx)

You can create a TemplateSelector and decide which template to apply based on a given item:

```
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate SimpleTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate ComplexTemplate { get; set; }

    public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
    {
        // Logic to decide which template to apply goes here

        return // Either SimpleTemplate or ComplexTemplate
    }
}
```

In xaml, add your template selector as a resource

```
<local:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="itemTemplateSelector">
            <local:MyTemplateSelector.SimpleTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <!-- Implementation goes here -->

                </DataTemplate>
            </local:MyTemplateSelector.SimpleTemplate>
            <local:MyTemplateSelector.ComplexTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <!-- Implementation goes here -->

                </DataTemplate>
            </local:MyTemplateSelector.ComplexTemplate>
</local:MyTemplateSelector>
```

And use it in your `ItemsControl`

```
<ItemsControl 
  x:Name="MainCanvas"
  DataContext="{StaticResource mainItems}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Buttons}"
  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource itemTemplateSelector}">
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I've tried this approach. But I get an error: "Error 4. The property 'ItemTemplateSelector' does not exist on the type 'ItemsControl'.

Comment: @Denis_Sh Are you sure you are using [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.aspx) from `System.Windows.Controls` namepsace in `PresentationFramework.dll`?.  as you can see in the MSDN documentation it has an [ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx) property ...

Comment: Sure. System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl

Comment: .NET 4.5, VS 2012, WPF version is 3.0.6920.4902

Comment: Target OS is Windows Phone 8

Comment: Here is my xaml: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_v2jBHEPR4VUUw4LUwwMEo0SDQ/edit?usp=sharing    All the data templates in separate resource dictionary

Comment: @Denis_Sh I can't compile it because I don't have windows 8 and I'm missing assembly references, but it does allow me to set the `ItemTemplateSelector` of the `ItemsControl`. I thought it might be because the `ItemsControl` of WPF and Windows Phone are different, but there is MSDN documentation on the [Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx) version as well. Maybe it's something with resource dictioranries. try setting it all in the `MapPage.xaml` see if that works

Comment: Probably they really have a different implementation for desktop Windows and Windows Phone. My test Windows application allows me to set 'ItemTemplateSelector' property. Really weird. Now I'm going to clarify this moment. Thanks!